# why i am getting this error when sending data through curl

Tags: php, curl

> Error: call to URL
>   https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CreateLoan/ failed with
>   status 400, response HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Sat, 27 Feb 2016
>   09:22:27 GMT Set-Cookie:
>   BrowserId=Dn8n41hbQLCLGe4ztf5mbg;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Wed,
>   27-Apr-2016 09:22:27 GMT Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
>   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked [{"message":"Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was
>   expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:25,
>   column:6]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}], curl_error , curl_errno
>   0

Comment: Can you post the payload JSON ?

Comment: welcome to SE, while asking a question always put as much information you can put with your question it will help other to understand your problem and provide a solution without any additional communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are passing a JSON which is not constructed properly.

- You have a trailing comma `,` at the end of last key-value pair, so JSON parse assumes you are going to declare few more variables. But since you abruptly close it with `}` it fails in parsing it.
- Assuming by the error message you have error at Line:25 column 6 your json string should look something like below>

**Payload:**

```
 json_string = '{ "a":"b", 
 .
 "field": "value",
 } // Line 25
```

**Solution:**

Remove the trailing comma and Change it to:

```
 json_string = '{ "a":"b", 
 .
 .
 "field": "value"
 } // Line 25
```

and it should work fine

Comment: Thanks @karthilselve. It works. It has solved my json error but it showing another error about partner code like following Error: call to URL https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CreateLoan/ failed with status 200, response HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 06:28:22 GMT Set-Cookie: BrowserId=Ac5bU4LPSGi6eBUg0wJdYg;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 30-Apr-2016 06:28:22 GMT Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked " message - Invalid Partner Code,", curl_error , curl_errno 0